# Google Autocomplete API - Focus on letter from middle

Tags: api, autocomplete, google-search-api

I'm trying to obtain suggestion from Google Autocomplete API by focusing one letter in the middle of two keywords. So google will auto complete everything for me after that.

Here is a example which I don't need, but they work:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=**is stackoverflow**

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=**stackoverflow is**

And here is a example which I need, but it doesn't work:

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=**is s amazing**

So basically I need to turn "is *letter* good" to results such as: "is Stackoverflow good", "is Supernatural good" and so on. But is seems like it doesn't work through api just like it works on google.

[image]

I really don't know what to do. Help me guys! :(